# How can I license networked applications?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, licensing, project-management

I have five applications residing on servers. Some of these applications are socket (C/C++) based, others are web based (Java, PHP). I need to give licenses to these applications on the basis of the number of users that can access, the type of functionalities and type of users. What kind of business model should I use? I have a few in mind:

1. Create a java webservice that will be mounted on a license data, and
   all the servers will communicate with it when a user logs in any of
   the above applications.
2. Do a socket based server.
3. Mount a lisence file on each server and make each one communicate
   with its file individually and act as the license rules.

If you have other solutions please shoot.

Regards.

Comment: @Gerep Can you please explain, why did you choose the first one and not the others? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been there and done that. I'd like to offer some leading questions on each approach.

A key piece of information is why are you trying to prevent unlicensed users from using your software? Is this an application open to the general public? Is this to protect/support sales and contractual obligations? Are your users friendly (might accidentally add new users) or hostile (will intentionally add users they don't have licenses for)?

Do your customers have access to your softwares configuration? To the hardware it runs on?

> Create a java webservice that will be mounted on a license data, and
>   all the servers will communicate with it when a user logs in any of
>   the above applications.

What happens if the license server is down or slow? Does this prevent logins? Will calling out to the license server on each login slow down the login enough to annoy the users?

Who will maintain this service? Who will add/update licenses?

How will you secure the communication with the license server?

> Do a socket based server.

This is the same overall approach as the first option. You should think of this in terms of "I have a remote license server". The protocols and techniques used to communicate with that server are important, but not as important as the overall design.

> Mount a lisence file on each server and make each one communicate with
>   its file individually and act as the license rules.

How will you generate and distribute these license files? Will you/your support team do it or the customer?

How will you secure the license files? A license file with a number in it will do, but is hardly adequate to really enforce licensing restrictions. A signed file is a step better. A cryptographically secured file is best, but may be overkill.

Comment: the customer may have alot of users, but has concrete number of licenses. what i gain from the license is to let only permitted number of users login. I am thinking to put the license server at the customers site besides all other servers. If the customer needs more users to login he needs to buy more licenses, you get the idea?

Comment: If the license server is down all the other applications will not let the users sign in anymore and the system will stop allowing any functionality to run.

Comment: If you require the customer to run the license server you're making work. A separate license server is another piece of software to install, run, maintain, and monitor. By forcing the software to hit the license server for each login, a minor problem which takes down the license server would then disable all the other software.

Comment: yes you are correct, but I think that central license server is better when taking into consideration the following details:

Comment: 1. a one license file is there that can rule over all the applications. There is no need to implement a module that uses cryptological and license creation/checking algorithm for each application in differnet languages.One only will be created at the central server

Comment: 2. When the central license server is down, it doesn't mean that all the other managed applications will stop from working. we can sebd messages to the network and bussiness administrations that a critical server is down. And will give some time break for all the servers untill the problem is fixed.

Comment: I think you're over-engineering the problem. Standing up an entire licensing service/server, that can bring other services down if it fails is a recipe for disaster. Why not create a license file that says how many users can use the software at once, sign it with a PGP key, and just upload that to the software. The software verifies the signature (so it can only come from you) then sets the maximum number of users.

Answer (score 2):

Solution #1 is probably the most elegant solution, as it centralizes all the licensing logic. Any changes can be done in one place. The main drawbacks to a licensing server (as compared to a local license file like #3) are performance and reliance on the availability of the licensing server. If the licensing server goes down, what do you want your applications to do? Block all access? Temporarily allow all access?

Comment: In a matter of fact, I need to block all access, because shutting down the server implies: we have no license to operate sir! We have some primary reasons acting like that as: The clients themselves may shut it down or play with it...etc.

Comment: Can you please give more interpretation and explanations for your answer, I think you are right, because I need to discuss this a lot!